# How to access the @keyframes selector and catch the value from there

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is code in css

```
 #shape {
   -webkit-animation: spin 50s infinite linear;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0); }
   100%   { transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
 }
```

I need to catch the moment of turning. Example : If the Y - axis rotation is -30 degrees , do the action

I tried a lot of things, but nothing came out. Used js and jquery

Comment: Have you tried using 8%?

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes generates only this events giving any information to JS:

- animationstart
- animationend
- animationiteration
- animationcancel

```css
  @keyframes sk-logo-main{
      0% { transform: rotate(-360deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  }

  #my-div-animated{
    background:#666699;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25px;
    position:absolute;
    
    animation-name: sk-logo-main;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
  }
```

```html
<div class='container'>

<div id="my-div-animated">
  text
</div>

</div>

  <script>
  
function AnimationListener( e ){
  console.log ( e ) ;
}

window.addEventListener ( 'load', ()=>{
  let animDiv = document.getElementById ( 'my-div-animated' );
  animDiv.addEventListener( "animationstart", AnimationListener);
  animDiv.addEventListener( "animationiteration", AnimationListener);
} );  
  
  </script>
```

You can not check animation progress state between this "states"/"events".

If you want to have full contronl at animated elements that you can do this animation in JS.